# Comprehensive list of all available !bangs on DuckDuckGo.com

Tags: duckduckgo

Recently I switched from Google to DuckDuckGo and so far I am very pleased with the experience.
"The Internet" tells me that one of DuckDuckGo's best features is the possibility to directly search on specific pages using **bangs** (defined prefixes). E.g. search for "!so [duck-duck-go]" on DuckDuckGo to get duck-duck-go tagged questions on Stackoverflow.

I was searching for a comprehensive list of all available bangs, but the only thing I found was the official [bang-page](https://duckduckgo.com/bang) wich offers a search box and categorized lists, but no **complete** list of all 7,447* bangs.

Is there a possibility to find all bangs without clicking through all the categories on the bang-page?

---

(*) by time of writing, 2015-12-15

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently you can turn off JavaScript or just visit https://duckduckgo.com/bang_lite.html

Kudos to x.15a2 from the DuckDuckGo-Forums!

Comment: interestingly, it looks like each bang can belong to more than one category, or to a single category more than once! :)

Answer (score 5):

There is an undocumented JavaScript file that contains all Bangs with their categories and URLs: https://duckduckgo.com/bang.v261.js (***updated September 25, 2023***)

My best guess as to what the object keys hold:

- `r`: Ranking
- `t`: Tag (Bang)
- `u`: URL
- `sc`: Sub category
- `d`: Domain
- `s`: Summary
- `c`: Main category

Here is an example entry of the `!so` bang:

```
[
    {
        "c": "Tech",
        "d": "stackoverflow.com",
        "r": 665,
        "s": "Stack Overflow",
        "sc": "Programming",
        "t": "so",
        "u": "http://stackoverflow.com/search?q={{{s}}}"
    }
    // ..
]
```

Comment: New link: https://duckduckgo.com/bang.v260.js