# How do I get the list of all DuckDuckGo Bangs with categories and history?

Tags: duckduckgo

***Is there a way to get the overall list of all [DuckDuckGo Bangs](https://duckduckgo.com/bang), together with the categories and history of each bang being introduced or modified?***

For example, I've noticed a few months ago that one of my sites, [!](http://duckduckgo.com/?q=!BXR)[BXR](http://bxr.su/), appears on the bang list.  However, today I've noticed that DuckDuckGo must have recently introduced the categories, as a two-level hierarchy, and I could only find my site on the first level "Tech", not on the second level "Programming" where I think it should belong as well, but I couldn't find out any more info (like whether it belongs to any second-level category at all, maybe even a more relevant one that I may have overlooked; I finally found it's at Sysadmin, but this involved a few too many manual attempts at listing each category individually).

Is there a way to see all DuckDuckGo bang sites, together with their categories?

I'm also curious when each site was added, possibly who added it, and, possibly an unrelated question, what's the procedure to modify it, if necessary?  For example, whoever added my site, appears to have restricted the search on it to symbol references (e.g., identifier search), whereas it is my expectations that most people would instead be interested in a full-text search.  (Also, any chance of getting any sort of search statistics?)

The question [Comprehensive list of all available !bangs on DuckDuckGo.com](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/87678) is similar to this one, but while that question only asks for a list of bangs, this question is asking for a list of bangs *with history and categories*.

Comment: Well, I guess what I'm looking for is the versioned version of the https://duckduckgo.com/bang_lite.html link from the above question, plus also containing the information of which actual URLs/sites each bang resolves to.

Comment: You could try contacting support at DuckDuckGo

Answer (score 3):

There is an undocumented JavaScript file that contains all Bangs with their categories and sub categories: https://duckduckgo.com/bang.v255.js

My best guess as to what the object keys hold:

- `c`: **Main category**
- `sc`: **Sub category**
- `r`: Ranking
- `t`: Tag (Bang)
- `u`: URL
- `d`: Domain
- `s`: Summary

Answer (score 1):

There does not seem to be a way to look at all of the bangs, mostly likely due to the large number of them (over 7,000), nor is there a way to view any data about them, as far as I'm aware. To modify it, you may want to try [posting a new bang](https://duckduckgo.com/newbang) and explaining in the comments that it is an update.